# Which Latex text editor appears in this image?

Tags: software

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this  question. So my apologies for any misunderstanding.

I would like to know which software is used in the video that is available in the following link:
[Video](https://ethz.zoom.us/rec/play/68Evdu77_W83E4XH4wSDBfF5W9W7J6usgyFM-PpZnhmzAnYFZFHwNOYRNLFINHyic0usWTp04EApmCMG?continueMode=true&_x_zm_rtaid=lfhV6pvYTGySeW23P6sCLg.1588659799082.2b80f723d322ba1d9be969c12ab39852&_x_zm_rhtaid=494)

Here is a relevant part of a single frame from the video:

[image]

Comment: Could be TeXshop. But why do you want to know? Just pick any and see if it comfortable to use. I don't use a LaTeX editor at all.

Answer (score 3):

I had no clue. But here's what I did. Looked up the single clue we had - [the file extension `.tm`](http://www.fileextensions.info/file-extension/tm).

Two matches came up:

- [GNU TeXmacs](https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html)
- WinTeXmacs (seemingly just a flavor of the above)

Next came an image search for GNU TeXmacs and [the result](https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/images/texmacs-chinese.png) is this:

[image: Texmacs]

I think we have a match.

**NB:**

> Documents can be saved in TeXmacs, Xml or Scheme format and printed as
>   Pdf or Postscript files. Converters exist for TeX/LaTeX and
>   Html/Mathml. **Notice that TeXmacs is not based on TeX/LaTeX.**